# Symfony dynamic form on every field

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to make a dynamic for in Symfony. I have an object, like `Article`, which i want to create with another object. For this, I need to add some fields to my form. 
I wonder if it's possible to had a dynamic choicefield. I have a form like :

```
$builder
    ->add('article', 'entity', array('class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Article',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'choices' => $articles,
                'multiple' => false))
```

Here, my choices list represent all of articles with names. I would like to had a new choice in this list like "new article". If this choice is selected, a field must be appear. This text field should be like "Name of this article" and when the form will be validate, the article will be create.

It's possible to create this form in Symfony ?
I tried [this](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-user-data) but I didn't see how to dynamize the form with the choices list.

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer: This may not be suitable/acceptable answer, but more of analyses of my previous attempts to solve this.***

I had several occurrence where I needed such a feature. Most of them ended up with mixed `JS` and `Symfony`, but nothing universal.

What I did back then was:

- Create a custom form field type, which wrap `entity`. This fields adds a `<button>` with some callback
- Target `twig` page renders the field and provides a `JS` callback for the `<button>` of form fields, which in turn calls some `Symfony` endpoint for creating entity object. Sort of REST but not really.
- Finally, upon processing `AJAX` call, I get the ID from `JSON` response and manually insert a new `<option>` into the `<select>` control and select it.

In case of `<select>` this is fairly easy to achieve, **but**, if you `choice` fields renders with `expanded => true`, you really need to work your magic around control's layout in order not to break it. This may end up somewhat painful :)

Hope this sheds some light on this topic...